# cant get ggplot2 to make a barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
# vector of storm types **in required order**
all_statuses <- c("hurricane","tropical storm", "tropical depression")
# convert `status` variable to a factor
storms <- storms %>% 
 mutate(status=factor(month.abb[month], levels = month.abb))
storms <- storms %>% 
  mutate(status = factor(status, levels = all_statuses))
# use updated storms data to make bar plot
ggplot(storms, 
       # N.B. species **already converted to factor**
       aes(x = month_fac, fill = all_statuses)) +
  # use geom_bar to add bar plot layer with stacked bars
  geom_bar()
```

Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (11859): fill - the error i keep getting
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You are mapping your (length 3) vector `all_statuses` on the fill aes. Maybe you want `fill = status`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would pipe everything:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

storms %>% 
  mutate(month_fac = factor(month.abb[month], levels = month.abb), ### as you did
         order = case_when(status == "hurricane" ~ 1,
                           status == "tropical storm" ~ 2,
                           status == "tropical depression" ~ 3), ### create order
         all_statuses = fct_reorder(status, order)) %>% ### create factor
  ggplot(aes(x = month_fac, fill = all_statuses)) +
  geom_bar()
```

Output is:

[image]

please be aware that there is no storm data for February and March. You need to add empty lines for that.

Comment: is there a way to do it without the forcats library?